# Go struct comparison

Tags: go, struct, comparison

The Go Programming Language Specification section on [Comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) leads me to believe that a struct containing only comparable fields should be comparable:

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-blank fields are equal.

As such, I would expect the following code to compile since all of the fields in the "Student" struct are comparable:

```go
package main

type Student struct {
  Name  string // "String values are comparable and ordered, lexically byte-wise."
  Score uint8  // "Integer values are comparable and ordered, in the usual way."
}

func main() {
  alice := Student{"Alice", 98}
  carol := Student{"Carol", 72}

  if alice >= carol {
    println("Alice >= Carol")
  } else {
    println("Alice < Carol")
  }
}
```

However, it [fails to compile](https://play.golang.org/p/Y7a_-QCFL-) with the message:

> invalid operation: alice >= carol (operator >= not defined on struct)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are correct, structs are **comparable**, but not **ordered** ([spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)):

> The equality operators `==` and `!=` apply to operands that are comparable. The ordering operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` apply to operands that are ordered.
>
> ...
>
> - Struct values are **comparable** if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-blank fields are equal.

`>=` is an ordered operator, not a comparable one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the field you're comparing to get the program to compile.

```
if alice.Score >= carol.Score
```

Then it compiles and prints

> Alice >= Carol