# I wonder how to implement set struct as map value

Tags: go

I want to use set as map value on golang. So I coded like this:

```
import (
   "fmt"
   "reflect"
)

type TestSet struct {
   Items []Test
}

func (ts *TestSet) Add(t *Test) {
   ok := true
   for _, item := range ts.Items {
      if item.Equal(t) {
         ok = false
         break
      }
   }
   if ok {
      ts.Items = append(ts.Items, *t)
   }
}

type Test struct {
   phoneNumber string
   name        string
   friends     []string // i add this field! (**edit**)
}

func (t *Test) Equal(t2 *Test) bool {
   if t.phoneNumber != t2.phoneNumber || t.name != t2.name {
      return false
   }
   if !reflect.DeepEqual(t.friends, t2.friends) {
      return false
   }
   return true
}
```

And I want to use structure like below code:

```
val := make(map[int]*TestSet)
val[1] = &TestSet{}
val[1].Add(&Test{phoneNumber: "8210", name: "minji", friends: []string{"myself"})
```

However my `TestSet` always has to iterate over the entire item to exist its value. So `Add()` time complexity O(n).

I want to reduce that time complexity to O(1). (like *python set*  `in`)

But, I do not know what to do. Should I use another map?

Any good ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by `val[1]`?

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma oops, I edit the samples!

Comment: But what you wrote on the question is not llike set rather than a map. Do you want to convert your map into a set implementation?

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma my english is not good, sorry ;( as a result, what i want is like this sample python code `a.setdefault(1, set()).add(Test())` a is dictionary. and a.values has always unique structure(i used custom class in python and override `__hash__` method). if map can do this, please help...

Comment: Do you want like this `val := make(map[int]*Test)` so that you can store the `Test` structs by order they are inserted?

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma i want to store `Test` __LIST__ and not duplicated. i don't care ordered or not...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183758/discussion-between-shudipta-sharma-and-minji).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sets are often implemented as maps with no value](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Set_(abstract_data_type)#/Implementations). A `struct{}` is effectively empty in Go.

```
type Empty struct {}

type TestSet struct {
   set map[Test]Empty
}
```

In order for this to work, `Test` must be [comparable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators).

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-blank fields are equal.

So `Test` is comparable.

```
package main;

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Empty struct {}

type TestSet struct {
    set map[Test]Empty
}

func (ts *TestSet) Add(t Test) bool {
    if _, present := ts.set[t]; present {
        return false
    } else {
        ts.set[t] = Empty{}
        return true
    }
}

type Test struct {
    phoneNumber string
    name        string
}

func main() {
    set := TestSet{ set: make(map[Test]Empty) }
    test1 := Test{ phoneNumber: "555-555-5555", name: "Yarrow Hock" }
    test2 := Test{ phoneNumber: "555-555-5555", name: "Yarrow Hock" }
    test3 := Test{ phoneNumber: "123-555-5555", name: "Yarrow Hock" }
    if set.Add( test1 ) {
        fmt.Println("Added 1")
    }
    if set.Add( test2 ) {
        fmt.Println("Added 2")
    }
    if set.Add( test3 ) {
        fmt.Println("Added 3")
    }

    for test := range set.set {
        fmt.Println(test.phoneNumber)
    }
}
```

You can also use [the golang-set library](https://github.com/deckarep/golang-set).

Comment: A map with no value uses `struct{}` as the value type for the map.

Comment: @ratorx How do you set that? `ts.set[t] = ?`

Comment: type Empty struct{}
    type TestSet struct {
       set map[Test]Empty
    }
    ...
    ts.set[t] = Empty

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma Got it. `ts.set[t] = struct{}{}`

Comment: You got that right.

Comment: if `Test` has field as a list. like `friends []string`. then `Test` can't be key type as a map. what should i do next?

Comment: @minji You could use an Array, `friends [5]string`. Otherwise you'd require the thing being added to the set to implement a [hash function](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hash_function) and use the hash as a key and store the thing as the value. `ts.set[thing.Hash()] = thing`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map to emulate a set in golang by making the value type `struct{}`. Some example code for your `Test` struct:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type TestSet map[Test]struct{}

func (ts TestSet) Add(t Test) {
    ts[t] = struct{}{}
}

type Test struct {
    phoneNumber string
    name string
}

func main() {
    ts := TestSet{}
    t1 := Test{"a", "b"}
    t2 := Test{"a", "b"}
    ts.Add(t1)
    ts.Add(t2)

    fmt.Println(ts) // Output: map[{a b}:{}]
}
```

This doesn't match your function signatures exactly, as I use values rather than references. This means that I don't have to define a custom `Equals` functions as you have done. Also, by passing in the argument as a value, the map checks the structs themselves for equality rather than the references.

A thing to note is that this method will only work if the structs are comparable. More info is in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643251/go-struct-comparison) which quotes the spec.