# How does Go handle comparison without a builtin Comparable interface?

Tags: go, interface, comparison

I found this question while I was researching the topic - [What is the comparable interface called in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122919/what-is-the-comparable-interface-called-in-golang), however it does not completely answers my question.

Let's say I have a simple type **Special**:

```
type Special struct {
    Value int
    IsActive bool
    Guid string
}
```

Now I want to use my custom type with a third party 'Binary tree' data structure. I guess there will be an interface included within the implementation of the Binary tree which I need to implement in order to use it with my custom type:

```
type Comparable interface{
    CompareTo(other Comparable) int
}
```

That's fine but what happens when I need to use another data structure, for example 'Sorted Linked List' ? I download a different package which has a different interface to implement:

```
type Comparable2 interface{
    Compare(other Comparable) int
}
```

In other words I need to add a different receiver functions (methods) to my type every time I need to use a data structure that should know how to compare my type ? That's a bit strange in my opinion. 
Am I missing something or how are these cases handled in software development with Go ?

Comment: "how are these cases handled in software development with Go ?" These cases are uncommon and not "handled" by the language. In doubt you just implement the two methods.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for an equivalent of C++20's "spaceship operator" (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison). This just doesn't exist in Go; you have to write your own.

Answer (score 3):

> How does Go handle comparison without a builtin Comparable interface?

It doesn't. It's up to you to implement comparison for custom types where it is needed. A common pattern, such as that found in the [time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Equal) package, is an `Equal()` method on your type, which takes another instance of the same type as an argument for comparison.

So for your example type:

```golang
type Special struct {
    Value int
    IsActive bool
    Guid string
}
```

This would look like this:

```golang
func (s Special) Equal(u Special) bool {
    return s.Value == u.Value &&
        s.IsActive == u.IsActive &&
        s.Guid == u.Guid
}
```

Although keep in mind, in this specific example, two structs of this type are directly comparable anyway, since all underlying types are directly comparable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39643329/13860) for more detail.

One still might choose to use direct comparison of each field (as I have demonstrated) if it's felt it adds clarity, or that the struct may grow to include non-comparable fields in the future.

If you're interested in comparison for the sake of ordering, this is an entirely different thing (and languages that pretend it's not are, in my opinion, fundamentally broken).

If your type can be consistently ordered, you can implement the [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) interface.  If you have a type that can be ordered in different ways, you may wish instead to use the [`sort.Slice`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice) method, which takes an arbitrary comparison function as an argument.

Comment: Actually Equal() does not help in comparing two objects in terms of which one is "bigger" - it only checks if both objects are equal and returns a bool value. My question was whether I need to implement the same comparing logic for different interfaces depending on what a the specific data structure uses ? Sounds like a double work to me ... Most languages (at least in my experience) have a system interface for comparison.

Comment: @dimitar.d "Most languages (at least in my experience) have a system interface for comparison." Like C or Pascal or Lisp? Someones experience is never large enough.

Comment: Most *object-oriented languages* do, but Go isn't object-oriented.